# mod_rewrite rewriting to local directory

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

The `.htaccess` we have in our `document_root` directory is as follows:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^posts/1/first-post-title$ /posts/1.html [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/posts/1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/^posts/1/first-post-title$
RewriteRule (.*) posts/1/first-post-title [R=301,L]
```

The configuration is designed so that the following URLs will all point to "http://localhost/posts/1/first-post-title":

- "http://localhost/posts/1"
- "http://localhost/posts/1/wrong-title"
- "http://localhost/posts/1/first-post-title"

The second line works fine and "http://localhost/posts/1/first-post-title" looks at /posts/1.html

Unfortunately, when either of the other to URLs are used, the user gets redirected to "http://localhost/path/to/document_root/posts/1/first-post-title"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your rewrite to be *absolute*, e.g. rather than this:

```
 RewriteRule (.*)  posts/...
```

Use this:

```
 RewriteRule (.*)   /posts/...
```